# in the response on the site gives out incomprehensible hieroglyphs

Tags: python, python-requests, request, response

when you try to display a get request in the text, it gives out incomprehensible characters, I would like it to produce normal text

Code:

```
    headers = {
        "authority": "www.ozon.ru",
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/product/playstation-5-digital-edition-339866183/?asb=ZdbNZjh%252BgUCDpV0uw5ZLJUkaSn2wNH%252FSaAKJ%252BAxhX2M%253D&asb2=ayxVVx0ddcEtoLM3AwfnfVSDeZSpnVMgJu1dkk3rkjo&keywords=playstation+5&sh=0OBU25Oz",
        "scheme": "https",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
        "cache-control": "max-age=0",
        "cookie": "__Secure-ext_xcid=704b112d0788105d7206457724d88846; _gcl_au=1.1.954892941.1622892064; visid_incap_2251426=KU5k7V3nRbi5hIuCe4vdFn1su2AAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADSheykofd2VQeH1V6sdne6; visid_incap_1101384=ng7gdJKQTtaTXDhwXw0BERteu2AAAAAAQkIPAAAAAACAxLmcAby/fnf6k3vP36Lor9I9dWxx3mbg; __Secure-ab-group=30; _abck=AD1EC4FEF31E5162861A4C24D2CA7963~-1~YAAQVxndWMOJ1Bl6AQAAzuyMdwYmY8viAq7FQPAI0crJs+Y7Tol5pA9DDuINFgy8m+dW33GrxDi2sthCys8Q8xdFoZ5b/+cj885D7t6jQxlVTWRyFksPOyCfG+aPZcNjWLG4gtLYGhig4GmVY2IhbziLiACrJVZ9tvvQe+bPDscWtCGH5oFB2KDTmr+/5anJzP52dInIJRinf0G36Uv6LmTBvJ5oqmtHns+wdvWHV2/XtFBwUrKukPL/yB4I534FenLEKBs/go7uQS0q8XCAoeXQuHxE+XXEHteC3ViGCfdsi83AQgjjXemaeBg6rIcc6GOo4HS+NPR/o20jeZaNPOw21BZoSvhmSzk3WWAoOxqjayhWTKVE/Uu0k/2n3yS2XuFjUsw9nmMtOslXKyWPHYWcAvAFzw==~-1~-1~-1; _gcl_dc=GCL.1631556671.CjwKCAjwyvaJBhBpEiwA8d38vJ0cwc6gyFvDIalkCBIdbC18GmVXVD0XxIgwZoz--ClC6ErOz2uVmRoCw6oQAvD_BwE; visid_incap_1285159=FmeU/lKJQvaWmkgD2CjChIi8QGEAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADss4s71kpz7hK78LrQuFFa; __Secure-user-id=0; _gcl_aw=GCL.1633529190.CjwKCAjwkvWKBhB4EiwA-GHjFrQIvq2PTJYu-I5iwQo9hU06pvsUVvjj37nTH7ACBQDGNCG1NvNHlBoCIvEQAvD_BwE; nlbi_1101384=wNPJODVEXFvoYA/LK8plmQAAAACQSMQv10AIEBv9M1qG+ZgE; incap_ses_584_1101384=8gq4QeKdPVbcmBCIpMkaCMfCZWEAAAAAxQKn2KtmDQeSxEYbjPxM4Q==; xcid=b0d40e42f20927f1b6ef2f74056069fb; incap_ses_633_1101384=NoBfaWnlixsskJIVP97ICA2dZmEAAAAARs7zxjAA1ruartIDr0d2SA==; __Secure-access-token=3.0.BrCcd3kzR2aUcKDrHyfVvw.30.l8cMBQAAAABhQLuyDO5qoKN3ZWKgAICQoA..20211013104710.f77kLnpPyPCZUz33bipJ1qSFh7n4QIBACd22xU-M_sE; __Secure-refresh-token=3.0.BrCcd3kzR2aUcKDrHyfVvw.30.l8cMBQAAAABhQLuyDO5qoKN3ZWKgAICQoA..20211013104710.CAQWWNrTHcPBdzYVN9iOE7QB4LwfW4rmHjDJEszki5A; incap_ses_585_1101384=y3r7Vz0DllfLWjWKF1ceCA2dZmEAAAAAne5pnSZ7U0xGgsv7j+fBMA==",
        "referer": "https://www.ozon.ru/cart",
        "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36",
    }
    
    r = requests.get('https://www.ozon.ru/product/playstation-5-digital-edition-339866183/?asb=ZdbNZjh%252BgUCDpV0uw5ZLJUkaSn2wNH%252FSaAKJ%252BAxhX2M%253D&asb2=ayxVVx0ddcEtoLM3AwfnfVSDeZSpnVMgJu1dkk3rkjo&keywords=playstation+5&sh=0OBU25Oz', headers=headers).text
    print(r)
```

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqaLJ.png)

how to make normal text output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting compressed output. (You could verify that by printing `r.headers` and looking at `Content-Encoding`.)

Remove the

```
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
```

request header because that claims you can accept `br`otli-compressed content, which Requests by default doesn't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified `accept-encoding`, the server performed compression before sending the data to you. ~~It's a Zip compression (begins with `PK`)~~

Just don't specify `accept-encoding` *at all* and the server will likely send you an uncompressed data stream.

[More about `accept-encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

Comment: The screenshot doesn't start with `PK`. Gzip streams don't start with `PK`, and Zip isn't Gzip.

Comment: (In addition, `requests` would handle `gzip` decompression transparently.)

Comment: Yeah my mistake. Confused about many things... I need a cuppa coffee...

Comment: Oh `requests` handle gzip automagically? Good to know. TIL